# how to trap more than one signal in c++?

Tags: c++, system

I know how to trap one signal

```
signal( SIGINT, handler );
```

but is there a way to trap more than one at same time ?

I tried `signal (SIGINT or SIGQUIT, handler)`

but its not work.

Comment: Just call `signal` again, once for each signal you want to handle.

Comment: you mean registering for multiple signals??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for signal(), it has been deprecated

you can register for multiple signals using sigaction.

```
struct sigaction act;
act.sa_handler = sighandler;
sigaction(SIGINT,  &act, 0);
sigaction(SIGTERM, &act, 0);
```

In the handler, you will get a signo which you can use to differentiate between them.

```
void sighandler(int signo)
{
   if (signo == SIGTERM || signo == SIGINT)
   {

   }
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can pass different functions to each invocation of `signal`, which may be slightly cleaner than inspecting the `signo` argument if there is absolutely no overlap in handler code.

Comment: agreed but that depends on the usecase